# Trying to set border on a JPanel using a child textfield

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield

I'm trying to set the border of a JPanel by using a child textfield.
I've tried using getParent(), but the option for setting the border does't exist. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Why not ensure that the action listener has a reference to the panel? BTW - what form is the information on the border, in the text field? If it is a number (for example) that is used in the constructor of an `EmptyBorder`, it would probably be more user friendly to have a `JSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel` as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getParent()` method returns a `Container` object.

The `setBorder(...)` method is only defined for `JComponent` objects.

So you need to cast the parent `Container` to a `JPanel`. Something like:

```
Container parent = textField.getParent();
JPanel panel = (JPanel)parent;
panel.setBorder( new LineBorder(Color.RED) );
```